# Write a random number generator that, based on uniformly distributed numbers between 0 and 1, samples from a Lévy-distribution?

Tags: python, random, probability, probability-distribution

I'm completely new to Python. Could someone show me how can I write a random number generator which samples from the [Levy Distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.levy.html)? I've written the function for the distribution, but I'm confused about how to proceed further!
The random numbers generated by this distribution I want to use them to simulate a 2D random walk.

I'm aware that from scipy.stats I can use the Levy class, but I want to write the sampler myself.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Levy distribution
"""
    f(x) = 1/(2*pi*x^3)^(1/2) exp(-1/2x)
"""
def levy(x):
    return 1 / np.sqrt(2*np.pi*x**3) * np.exp(-1/(2*x))

N = 50
foo = levy(N)
```

Comment: So far this is just encoding the formula, not actually writing the sampler, so its not really a debug question. From your research about how to do sampling you can write code and then come back with any problems you encounter along the way.

Comment: Why not using the provided generator: `scipy.stats.levy.rvs(size=1)`?

Comment: Given uniform (0, 1) samples, a standard approach to generate samples from another distribution which has cumulative distribution function F is to compute F^(- 1)(u) where u is the uniform sample and F^(- 1) is the inverse of the cdf. You have the density function so far; remember the cdf F(x) is the integral of the density up to x (or maybe you can just look up the cdf).

Comment: @RobertDodier Can you show me how to do this in python?

Comment: @Advaita Well, I like to give hints about the general approach. I assume that you can work out the details. I guess the first thing to figure out is how to implement the inverse of the cdf. Looks like the reference given by pjs has a formula for that -- you could work on implementing that.

Comment: Well, thank you for accepted answer, but, I believe,  it should go to @pjs. I didn't write a single line of sampling routine and that was the gist of the question - I only wrote comprehensive and useful testing.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux And did a darn good job of it!  I assumed the Wikipedia page was correct, you showed otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@pjs code looks ok to me, but there is a discrepancy between his code and what SciPy thinks about Levy - basically, sampling is different from PDF.

Code, Python 3.8 Windows 10 x64

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import levy
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng(312345)

# Arguments
#   u: a uniform[0,1) random number
#   c: scale parameter for Levy distribution (defaults to 1)
#   mu: location parameter (offset) for Levy (defaults to 0)
def my_levy(u, c = 1.0, mu = 0.0):
    return mu + c / (2.0 * (norm.ppf(1.0 - u))**2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

rnge=(0, 20.0)

x = np.linspace(rnge[0], rnge[1], 1001)

N = 200000
q = np.empty(N)

for k in range(0, N):
    u = rng.random()
    q[k] = my_levy(u)

nrm = levy.cdf(rnge[1])
ax.plot(x, levy.pdf(x)/nrm, 'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='levy pdf')
ax.hist(q, bins=100, range=rnge, density=True, alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

produce graph

[image]

UPDATE

Well, I tried to use home-made PDF, same output, same problem

```
# replace levy.pdf(x) with PDF(x)
def PDF(x):
    return np.where(x <= 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 / np.sqrt(2*np.pi*x**3) * np.exp(-1./(2.*x)))
```

UPDATE II

After applying @pjs corrected sampling routine, sampling and PDF are aligned perfectly. New graph

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward implementation of the [generating algorithm for the Levy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_distribution#Random_sample_generation) found on Wikipedia:

```
import random
from scipy.stats import norm

# Arguments
#   u: a uniform[0,1) random number
#   c: scale parameter for Levy distribution (defaults to 1)
#   mu: location parameter (offset) for Levy (defaults to 0)
def my_levy(u, c = 1.0, mu = 0.0):
    return mu + c / (2 * norm.ppf(1.0 - u)**2)

# Generate a handful of samples
for _ in range(10):
    print(my_levy(random.random()))
```

I don't normally use Python, so please suggest improvements.

---

**ADDENDUM**

Kudos to Severin Pappadeux for the work in his response.  I had already noted that a simpler answer would be to take the inverse of a squared Gaussian, but Advaita had asked for an explicit function of U ~ Uniform(0,1) so I didn't pursue that.  It turns out that I should have.  The Wikipedia cite mentions that, but without the scale factor of 2 in the denominator.  When I take the 2 out of the implementation of Wikipedia's generating algorithm, i.e. change the implemention to

```
def my_levy(u, c = 1.0, mu = 0.0):
    return mu + c / (norm.ppf(1.0 - u)**2)
```

the resulting histogram aligns beautifully with the normalized plot of the pdf.  (Note - I've now also edited the incorrect Wikipedia entry to correct the formula.)

Comment: there might be some problem with ... (with what?), please take a look at my answer. I'm too tired to figure it out now, going to sleep.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux You're right!  Wikipedia has the inversion wrong, it's off by a factor of 2 in the denominator.

Comment: Great! Updated with new graph, now everything is perfectly aligned.